# How to verify icon state using Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

How to verify that icon is not displayed or icon is displayed on the page ?

Image:
[image]

Here it is html code if icon is not displayed:

```
<td id="messageGrid_tccell1_7" class="txtleft dxgv"/>
```

Here it is html code if icon is displayed:

```
<td id="messageGrid_tccell2_7" class="txtleft dxgv">
<div class="locked" title="locked"/>
</td>
```

Comment: What is the behavior of this icon on webpage. Can explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the [ExpectedConditions class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs).

For example, if you call `ElementIsVisible()` with the locator of the inner `<div>` element it will only return true if it's there.

Comment: Can someone show a  sample code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
WebElement element=driver.findelement(By.id("messageGrid_tccell2_7"))
if(element.isdisplay())
{
System.out.println("Image displayed")
}else{
System.out.println("Image notdisplayed")
}
```

Comment: "messageGrid_tccell2_7" is the cell in which there is an icon or not.
The cell is still present.
So, this code can not be used to verify the status of the icon.